# foreach loop accepts only the first index of array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, oop, foreach

I made a simple example in PHP, the objective is simply insert the values of the array to the database. The field names are the array keys and the field values are the array values. I chose object-oriented style for querying because I'm practising OOP. When I looped it, the issue was this: the code only accepts the first index of the array, which is the "name"; it is supposed to accept the four values since the table consists of four fields (name, email, username, password). Now the result in the database is only the name field has value, the rest of the fields are null. Here is the code:

```
<?php

class User {
    public static function insert($table, $table_fields = array()) {
        if(count($table_fields)) {
            foreach($table_fields as $field_name => $field_value) {
                return "INSERT INTO $table ($field_name) VALUES ('$field_value')";
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'sample');

mysqli_query($connect, User::insert('users', array(
    'name' => 'Sample Name',
    'email' => 'samplename@samplemail.com',
    'username' => 'sampleusername',
    'password' => '12345'
)));

?>
```

I want to know what's wrong with my code, and it would give me much more gratitude if you give me tips for improvement.

Comment: The first return will end the function execution.

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel trying to create your own active record function, you should look up on an already existent one, like [PHP ActiveRecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/)

Comment: Also, don't build queries *by hand*, **always** use [prepared statements](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Even though you need to remove the return, you know that foreach will not magically know that you want to append your keys one after another separated by comma?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes no one reinvented the wheel here. Your suggestion to use AR is just one of many useless pattern examples to create more problems than to solve any of the existing ones ..

Comment: maybe prepared statements can help

Answer (score -1):

Code bellow will make your example work, if you still want to use foreach you need to put return after it.
And like comments pointed you need to use prepared statements or some library to build your queries.

```
   <?php

class User {
    public static function insert($table, $table_fields = array()) {
        if(count($table_fields)) {
            return "INSERT INTO $table ('".implode("','",array_keys($table_fields))."') 
                            VALUES ('".implode("','",$table_fields)."')";
        }
        return false;
    }
}

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'sample');
mysqli_query($connect, User::insert('users', array(
    'name' => 'Sample Name',
    'email' => 'samplename@samplemail.com',
    'username' => 'sampleusername',
    'password' => '12345'
)));
```

Comment: Your code is wrong, VALUES ('".implode("','",$table_fields)."')";;   syntax error;